# can not deploy site to heroku , showing error

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment

added requirement.txt, Procfile,
receving error while deploying site to heroku
what could be wrong with this

```
Enumerating objects: 110, done.
Counting objects: 100% (110/110), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (106/106), done.
Writing objects: 100% (110/110), 13.54 MiB | 1.30 MiB/s, done.
Total 110 (delta 35), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
remote: -----> *App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack- 
 registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz*
 remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
 remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to covidcms.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/covidcms.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/covidcms.git'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to rename your `requirement.txt` file to `requirements.txt`

Heroku automatically recognizes your app as a Python app if it includes a requirements.txt or setup.py file in its root directory.

When a deployed application is recognized as a Python application, you’ll see this in the build output:

```
   $ git push heroku master
    -----> Python app detected
```

for more information check official doc. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#recognizing-a-python-app